# If & match function together in spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I wrote this formula in the spreadsheet: `=if(match(AR$2,$A5:$E5,0),AR$2,"")`

If there is no match, it's supposed to leave the cell blank, instead it gives #N/A. but if there is a match, it gives the value.  Can anybody show me how to correct this? thanks.

Comment: if you juste write `=match(AR$2,$A5:$E5,0)` in your cell, what does it give you?

Comment: when the values match, then it gives the value. if no match, then it still gives #N/A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `iferror`

try something like:

```
=iferror(if(match(AR$2,$A5:$E5,0),AR$2),"")
```

Comment: Thanks, Liora. it works. I am new to spreadsheets, why I need iferror here though.

Comment: The function `match` doesn't actually check is a value is in a range, it checks *where* the value is, so if the value isn't there, it returns `#N/A`.

Comment: I got it. Thanks again.